# WordPress database error occur when installing wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, error-handling, database-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1x9R.png)
This is a problem has occurred when I installing WordPress

Comment: As the error suggest you need to take a look at your mysqladmin and find out if there's already an installation that's sitting there, this might be caused by installation that was done in the past or was corrupted in the middle of previous installation

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the existing database and create a new or change the table prefix from wp_ to something else. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is your database have already all tables and you are trying to install WordPress using this table.

For the ideal scenario when you install fresh WordPress please use the new database rather than the old database.

So, please create new database and change the name in you **wp-config.php** file for **DB_NAME**.

Here I have shared the screens-shot for better understanding.

Screen-shot: https://prnt.sc/12aedo6

I hope it will helpful.